# R list of data.frames, mean summarise grouping by common factor variable

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr, summarize

I have a list of data.frames, with 3 variables each: date, value, key.

I'd like to group each data frame by the key factor, and compute row-wise mean (ie: by date).

Here's a toy example:

```
set.seed(123)

dates <- seq(from = as.Date("2018-06-18"), to = as.Date("2018-06-22"), length.out = 5)
fake_list <- list(d1 = data.frame(date = dates, value = rnorm(5), key = "aaa"),
              d2 = data.frame(date = dates, value = rnorm(5), key = "bbb"),
              d3 = data.frame(date = dates, value = rnorm(5), key = "aaa"),
              d4 = data.frame(date = dates, value = rnorm(5), key = "bbb"))
```

The result should be something along the line of:

```
fake_result <- list(d_aaa = data.frame(date = dates, mean_value = c(0.3318031, 0.06481816, 0.9797399, 0.09059554, -0.2132767)),
                d_bbb = data.frame(date = dates, mean_value = c(1.750989, 0.4793833, -1.615839, 0.0072515, -0.4592267)))
```

Basically I need to get the mean value by date, aggregating first by the key factor.

Hope this is clear enough, thanks in advance.

Also, dates could be of different length inside the list (data frames with different nrows()), this gives another challenge to the problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option

```
library(tidyverse)
fake_list %>% 
  bind_rows() %>% 
  group_by(key, date) %>% 
  summarise(value = mean(value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
# as.data.frame() %>%
  split(., .$key) %>% 
  map(., select, -key)
#$aaa
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#  date         value
#  <date>       <dbl>
#1 2018-06-18  0.332 
#2 2018-06-19  0.0648
#3 2018-06-20  0.980 
#4 2018-06-21  0.0906
#5 2018-06-22 -0.213 
#
#$bbb
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#  date          value
#  <date>        <dbl>
#1 2018-06-18  1.75   
#2 2018-06-19  0.479  
#3 2018-06-20 -1.62   
#4 2018-06-21  0.00725
#5 2018-06-22 -0.459
```

The idea is to create one `data.frame` / `tibble`, do the `group_by` and `summarise` operations before we `split` the data such that we end up with a list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nest` too from `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyverse)

fake_result <- fake_list %>% 
  do.call(rbind, .) %>% 
  group_by(key, date) %>%
  summarise(mean_value = mean(value)) %>% 
  group_by(key) %>% 
  nest()

fake_result

# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  key   data            
#  <fct> <list>          
#1 aaa   <tibble [5 x 2]>
#2 bbb   <tibble [5 x 2]>


fake_result$data

#[[1]]
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#  date       mean_value
#  <date>          <dbl>
#1 2018-06-18     0.332 
#2 2018-06-19     0.0648
#3 2018-06-20     0.980 
#4 2018-06-21     0.0906
#5 2018-06-22    -0.213 

#[[2]]
## A tibble: 5 x 2
#  date       mean_value
#  <date>          <dbl>
#1 2018-06-18    1.75   
#2 2018-06-19    0.479  
#3 2018-06-20   -1.62   
#4 2018-06-21    0.00725
#5 2018-06-22   -0.459
```